# Cannot install build-essentials/GCC on Kubuntu 11.10?

Tags: linux, kubuntu, gcc

I recently installed kubuntu 11.10 but to my surprise there is no gcc installed on it.Because of this I cannot install virtual box guest additions(they require the make utility) and I am not able to do development work using c/c++.

I did the standard installation and everything was/is running fine.I think if I do the kubuntu's full installation I may get gcc installed.But I'm new to linux and want to learn the way softwares are added/removed from the system.I played around and found the following:

1.The dolphin file manager is showing the kubuntu dvd properly

2.the drive seems to be mounted here : "/media/kubuntu 11.10i386".If I do ls on this path I'm able to see the dvd's contents.

3.The muon pckg. mgr. is able to list the various packages from the dvd but is not able to install them.The error message says : "cannot download package from cdrom:........." etc.

I think muon is looking at the directory cdrom which co-exists with "kubuntu 11.10i386" directory at /media/ but it is empty.So can I make muon to look at the kubuntu directory instead of the empty cdrom or there is something else going wrong.

Guys I'm new to linux so please be gentle..

Config :

Base m/c windows7 x86,kubuntu 11.10 x86 as guest using virtual box 4.1.6

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

to open a terminal window press ALT+F2, enter `konsole` press return. After that you can enter commands (press return after every line and enter your password when prompted). If you have no internet connection and want to enable the package manager to get packages from the cd, execute the following command. If you have an internet connection, the following command is not needed:

```
sudo sed -i "/^# deb cdrom.*/ s/^# //" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

after enabling (or not) the cdrom as a packet source, you can enter the following commands to install build-essential:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

you can also enable the cdrom in the muon packet manager. You should find the checkbox under *Settings* > *manage software sources* > Tab *other Software*. The menue points could be named slightly different because I am using a german translation and don't know how the original names are.